# Combine emissions of Observable

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm new to `RxJava` and what I want to do is `filter()` all Strings of an `Array` and from the new Array with the filtered strings to update my RecyclerView.

I tried :

```
         Observable.from(suggestionsArray)
            .filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(String item) {
                    return item.contains(usersTextEntered);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String i) {
                    adapter.addItem(i);
                }
            });

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where `suggestionsArray` is the Array of Strings I have initially and as you can see I use `filter()` to filter only those strings that contain a specific string and then update the adapter but what I get is a `ConcurrentModificationException` and I'm guessing this is because each item from filter comes one after other so I think I need something to `combine` all emissions before entering the `subscriber`.

I searched `RxJava` wiki for operators but everything I have found( merge/combine/zip etc ) has to do with two different `Observables` so I'm guessing I should search for something else to combine the emissions but I'm not sure how to search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you specify where is the source of exception ( i.e. stack trace ), its just guessing. But to answer your question about joining the items altogether, you can do that by `toList()` operator. It waits for the onComplete call and emits all items as one event in a form of List.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, where does the `ConcurrentModificationException` come from? A List? the Adapter?

If the latter, you could always defer to the main thread:

```
     Observable
     .from(suggestionsArray)
     .filter(item -> item.contains(usersTextEntered))
     .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(adapter::addItem, err ->{}, adapter::notifyDataSetChanged);
```